# How to keep the order intact as it is in the response got from the API call using vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, template-literals

I'm trying to fetch the **list of products** from the API with passing the query for **ascending** and **descending orders**. After clicking **desc** from the dropdown, the response I'm getting is correct but the order in which it should list out the elements in the page is getting wrong.

Any help with the problem would be appreciated. I have attached the below image as a problem reference:

[image: Output]

I have shared the below code and a **[Test Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-ordering-tlj4tf)** for your reference.

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const table = document.createElement("table");
const loader = document.createElement("div");
const API_URL = `https://fakestoreapi.com`;
let ORDER = `asc`;
loader.innerHTML = `Loader..`;

function hideLoader() {
  app.removeChild(loader);
}

function showLoader() {
  app.appendChild(loader);
}

app.innerHTML = `
<h1>List</h1>
`;

const select = document.createElement("select");
const option1 = document.createElement("option");
const option2 = document.createElement("option");
option1.value = "aesc";
option1.innerHTML = "aesc";
option2.value = "desc";
option2.innerHTML = "desc";
select.appendChild(option1);
select.appendChild(option2);
app.appendChild(select);
select.addEventListener("change", (e) => handleChange(e));

function handleChange(e) {
  fetchData(e.target.value);
}

async function fetchData(order) {
  showLoader();
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/products?sort=${order}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  displayData(data);
}

function displayData(data) {
  const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  console.log("data", data);
  data.forEach((item) => {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.key = item.id;
    tr.innerHTML = `
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.title}</td>
        <td>${item.price}</td>
    `;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  app.appendChild(table);
  hideLoader();
}

fetchData(ORDER);
```

Comment: You're adding data into a new table on click by using the function `handleChange` simply triger removing data . from your table there or removing the table directly , and then call the `fetchData` . A good practise would be to maintain a array intead of direclty adding tables

Comment: btw ... there is a typo ... twice `'aesc'` instead of  `'asc'`  for the `option1.value` and `option1.innerHTML`, though it's not the misbehaviors cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that a new table is added each time we call the API.

If we remove any existing table before adding the products, the issue will be resolved.

```
// Remove table and rebuild if it exists.
let tbody = document.getElementById("productTable");
if (tbody) {
    tbody.remove();
}
```

Full code snippet:

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const table = document.createElement("table");
const loader = document.createElement("div");
const API_URL = `https://fakestoreapi.com`;
let ORDER = `asc`;
loader.innerHTML = `Loader..`;

function hideLoader() {
  app.removeChild(loader);
}

function showLoader() {
  app.appendChild(loader);
}

  app.innerHTML = `
<h1>List</h1>
`;

const select = document.createElement("select");
const option1 = document.createElement("option");
const option2 = document.createElement("option");
option1.value = "aesc";
option1.innerHTML = "aesc";
option2.value = "desc";
option2.innerHTML = "desc";
select.appendChild(option1);
select.appendChild(option2);
app.appendChild(select);
select.addEventListener("change", (e) => handleChange(e));

function handleChange(e) {
  fetchData(e.target.value);
}

async function fetchData(order) {
  showLoader();
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/products?sort=${order}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  displayData(data);
}

function displayData(data) {
  // Remove table and rebuild if it exists.
  let tbody = document.getElementById("productTable");
  if (tbody) {
    tbody.remove();
  }
  tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  tbody.setAttribute("id", "productTable");
  
  console.log("data", data);
  data.forEach((item) => {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.key = item.id;
    tr.innerHTML = `
        <td>${item.id}</td>
        <td>${item.title}</td>
        <td>${item.price}</td>
    `;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  app.appendChild(table);
  hideLoader();
}

fetchData(ORDER);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You stated that the response you were getting was correct, but that the data was being rendering in the wrong order.

But that is wrong. The new (descending) data was being added onto the current table. As per the Test Demo Link you provided.

What you need to do is to remove the data in the current table, instead of added onto it.

Try this:

```
function displayData(data) {
  let tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")?.item(0);

  if (!tbody) {
    tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  }
  if (tbody) {
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
  }
  ...
```

It is checking it the table body exists, if it doesn't, it is created. Otherwise it table data is cleaned to prepare it for the new data.